Docker logs freeze
I start a simple docker container:
docker run python bash -c $'python -c \"import time\ncounter = 0\nwhile True:\n\tprint(counter)\n\tcounter = counter + 1\n\ttime.sleep(0.1)\"'

When I start it, it hangs for three minutes, then writes about 1800 lines of output and freezes for another several minutes.
What am I doing wrong? Can I make it show my logs in real time?

Why use bash to run python? Just docker run python python -c "blabla"

Does Why doesn't Python app print anything when run in a detached docker container? answer your question?


Can I make it show my logs in real time?

docker run runs without allocated pseudoterminal, so the output of a command is fully buffered. To unbuffer python process, see Disable output buffering , https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUNBUFFERED etc. Consider researching output buffering.

Thank you so much, enabling tty in docker helped!
